# How to add structure to the STL list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, list, data-structures, stl

i had an global structure like this:-

```
struct MachineList
    {
    BSTR AccountId;
    BSTR MachineId;
    BSTR Make;
    char* Make1;
    BSTR Model;
    char* Model1;
    BSTR SerialNumber;
    BSTR IpAddress1;
    char* IpAddress;
    BSTR Port1;
    int Port;
    BSTR LocationCode;
    SOCKET Sock;
    BSTR Status;
} MACHINELIST,*PMACHINELIST;
int MachineCount=-1;
```

I had an XML which i parse and store it in structure like this:-
 i want to add every structure that is filled by parsing into the stl list so i added the following code

```
vector<struct  MACHINELIST > SS;
```

Now i get the following error :-

> error C2371: 'MACHINELIST' : redefinition; different basic types error
>   C2512: 'MACHINELIST' : no appropriate default constructor available

```
int GetMachineList(char *Xmlpath)
{
    wLog->WriteDebugLog("Inside GetMachineList\n");
    try 
    {
        //Qualify namespase explicitly to avoid Compiler Error C2872 "ambiguous symbol" during linking.
        //Now Msxml2.dll use the "MSXML2" namespace
        //(see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316317):
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr docPtr;//pointer to DOMDocument object
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr NodeListPtr;//indexed access. and iteration through the collection of nodes
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr DOMNodePtr;//pointer to the node

        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode *pIDOMNode = NULL;//pointer to element's node
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode *pIParentNode = NULL;//pointer to parent node
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode *pIAttrNode = NULL;//pointer to attribute node
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNamedNodeMapPtr DOMNamedNodeMapPtr;//iteration through the collection of attribute nodes
        MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeList *childList=NULL;//node list containing the child nodes


        //Variable with the name of node to find: 
        BSTR strFindText  = L" ";//" " means to output every node

        //Variables to store item's name, parent, text and node type:
        BSTR bstrItemText,bstrItemNode, bstrItemParent,bstrNodeType;

        //Variables to store attribute's name,type and text:     
        BSTR bstrAttrName, bstrAttrType, bstrAttrText;

        HRESULT hResult;

        int i = 0;//loop-index variable
        int n = 0;//lines counter


        //Initialize COM Library:
        CoInitialize(NULL);

        //Create an instance of the DOMDocument object:
        docPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30));

        // Load a document:
        _variant_t varXml(Xmlpath);//XML file to load//uncomment this
        _variant_t varResult((bool)TRUE);//result 

        varResult = docPtr->load(varXml);

        if ((bool)varResult == FALSE)
        {
            wLog->WriteErrorLog("failed to load XML file. Check the file name\n");
            printf("failed to load XML file. Check the file name\n");

            return 1;
        }

        //Collect all or selected nodes by tag name:
        NodeListPtr = docPtr->getElementsByTagName(strFindText);//original
        // NodeListPtr=   docPtr->documentElement->getElementsByTagName(strFindText) ;



        //Output the number of nodes:
        //printf("Number of nodes: %d\n", (NodeListPtr->length));

        //Output root node:
        docPtr->documentElement->get_nodeName(&bstrItemText);
        //%ls formatting is for wchar_t* parameter's type (%s for char* type):
        printf("\nRoot: %ls\n", bstrItemText);  



**PMACHINELIST MachineList;**



        for(i = 0; i < (NodeListPtr->length); i++)
        {

            if (pIDOMNode) pIDOMNode->Release();            
            NodeListPtr->get_item(i, &pIDOMNode);


            if(pIDOMNode )
            {               

                pIDOMNode->get_nodeTypeString(&bstrNodeType);

                //We process only elements (nodes of "element" type): 
                BSTR temp = L"element";

                if (lstrcmp((LPCTSTR)bstrNodeType, (LPCTSTR)temp)==0) 
                {
                    n++;//element node's number
                    printf("\n\n%d\n", n);//element node's number
                    printf("Type: %ls\n", bstrNodeType);

                    pIDOMNode->get_nodeName(&bstrItemNode);
                    if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"ModuleSettings"))
                    {
                        isModuleSettings=TRUE;
                        //MS.account_id_name
                        printf("");
                    }


                    printf("Node: %ls\n", bstrItemNode);                
                    if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Machine"))
                    {
if(MachineCount++!=-1)
                        {
                            SS.push_back(MachineList);
                        }
                        //printf("value of count is %d\n",count);
                        count++;
                        //printf("value of count is %d\n",count);

                        isMachineList=TRUE;

                        **MachineList=new MACHINELIST;
                        MachineCount++;**
                        //MS.account_id_name

                    }
                    if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"/Machine"))
                    {
                        printf("detected");
                    }
                    pIDOMNode->get_text(&bstrItemText);
                    printf("Text: %ls\n", bstrItemText);
                    if(isModuleSettings)//work here
                    {
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"capture_local_dir"))
                        {
                            CapturelocalDir=bstrItemText;
                            printf("CapturelocalDir is %ls\n",CapturelocalDir);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"capture_log_dir"))
                        {
                            CapturelogDir=bstrItemText;
                            printf("CapturelogDir is %ls\n",CapturelogDir);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"capture_log_level"))
                        {
                            CapturelogLevel=bstrItemText;
                            printf("CapturelogLevel is %ls\n",CapturelogLevel);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"capture_request_interval"))
                        {
                            CapturerequestInterval=bstrItemText;
                            printf("CapturerequestInterval is %ls\n",CapturerequestInterval);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"capture_connection_interval"))
                        {
                            CaptureConnectionInterval=bstrItemText;
                            printf("CaptureConnectionInterval is %ls\n",CaptureConnectionInterval);
                        }
                    }
                    if(isMachineList)
                    {
                    /*  PMACHINELIST MachineList;
                        MachineList=new MACHINELIST;*/


                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"MachineId"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].MachineId=bstrItemText;
                            //MachineList.MachineId=bstrItemText;
                            MachineList->MachineId=bstrItemText;
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"IpAddress"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].IpAddress=bstrItemText;
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].IpAddress1=_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrItemText);
                            printf("ip address1 is %s\n",m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].IpAddress1);
                            MachineList->IpAddress=_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrItemText);
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Port"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Port=bstrItemText;
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Port1=_wtoi(bstrItemText);
                            MachineList->Port==_wtoi(bstrItemText);
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                            printf("port1 is %d\n",m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Port1);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Model"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Model=bstrItemText;
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Model1=_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrItemText);
                            MachineList->Model1=_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrItemText);
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Make"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Make=bstrItemText;
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].Make1=_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrItemText);
                            MachineList->Make1=_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrItemText);
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"SerialNumber"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].SerialNumber=bstrItemText;
                            MachineList->SerialNumber=bstrItemText;
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"AccountId"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].AccountId=bstrItemText;
                            MachineList->AccountId=bstrItemText;
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                        if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"location_code"))
                        {
                            m_LocalStorage.machinelist[count].LocationCode=bstrItemText;
                            MachineList->LocationCode=bstrItemText;
                            //printf("Machine id is %ls\n",ML[count].MachineId);
                        }
                    }




                    //Get the attributes:
                    int j = 0;//loop-index variable
                    long length;// number of attributes in the collection

                    DOMNamedNodeMapPtr = pIDOMNode->attributes;

                    hResult = DOMNamedNodeMapPtr->get_length(&length);


                }
            }
        }

        //Do not forget to release interfaces:
        pIDOMNode->Release();
        pIDOMNode = NULL;
        //pIParentNode->Release();
        pIParentNode = NULL;


    } 

    catch(...)
    {
        wLog->WriteErrorLog("Exception occurred while parsing XML\n");

    }


    CoUninitialize();
        printf("value of machine count is %d",MachineCount);
    wLog->WriteDebugLog("Ends GetMachineList\n");
    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a vector of any type, you need to pass the type as a template parameter. In your case, the type is `MachineList`:

```
vector<MachineList> SS;
```

To add an instance, you can use for example `push_back()`:

```
SS.push_back(MACHINELIST); // add the MACHIHELIST instance
SS.push_back(MachineList()); // add a default constructed MachineList.
```

In your code, `MACHINELIST` is an instance of type `MachineList`.

**Edit in response to comments**: if you wanted to store pointers, you would need a vector of pointers:

```
vector<MachineList*> SS;
```

Then you can add entries thus:

```
MachineList* m = new MachineList;
SS.push_back(m);
```

You are responsible for deleting the pointer to deallocate the dynamically allocated resources at the appropriate moment. i would suggest using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of raw ones, but you have more fundamental problems in your code.

Comment: sir thanks for the reply now i want to add the structure pointer that was created using new so i did the following in the above code if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Machine"))
     {
      if(MachineCount++!=-1)
      {
       SS.push_back(MachineList);
      }
      //printf("value of count is %d\n",count);
      count++;
      //printf("value of count is %d\n",count);
      
      isMachineList=TRUE;
      
      MachineList=new MACHINELIST;
      MachineCount++;
      
      

     }i am getting the following error error C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PMACHINELIST' to 'MACHINELIST &&'

Comment: @Dany unfortunately, a pointer to an X and X are not the same, so you cannot insert a pointer to a `MachineList` into a `vector<MachineList>`.

Comment: sir how can now i add the structure that i created using new?

Comment: @ juanchopanza at this line MachineList* m = new MachineList; it is saying m undefined

Comment: using List stl how can we get the first node of list i mean is there any function available in stl to get the node one by one

Comment: sir how to access the structure that has been added in the list,can you give an example?

Comment: @Dany see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), particularly `ftont()` and `back()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18814/discussion-between-dany-and-juanchopanza)

Comment: Sir can you please tell if some time in future i want to update status field in the structure that has been added into the list how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
vector< MachineList > SS;
```

`MachineList` is the name of your struct. `MACHINELIST` is an instance of the struct. `*PMACHINELIST` is a pointer to such a struct.

Comment: sir thanks for the reply now i want to add the structure pointer that was created using new so i did the following in the above code if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Machine")) { if(MachineCount++!=-1) { SS.push_back(MachineList); } //printf("value of count is %d\n",count); count++; //printf("value of count is %d\n",count); isMachineList=TRUE; MachineList=new MACHINELIST; MachineCount++; }i am getting the following error error C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PMACHINELIST' to 'MACHINELIST &&' –

Comment: thanks for the solution using List stl how can we get the first node of list i mean is there any function available in stl to get the node one by one

Answer (score 0):

Use `vector<MachineList>`.  When you declare with `struct MachineList { ... };` it creates a type `MachineList` which is known to be a struct and doesn't require prefixing with `struct` to use it.

Following the declaration with `MACHINELIST,*PMACHINELIST` is C-style code and unnecessary.

Comment: sir thanks for the reply now i want to add the structure pointer that was created using new so i did the following in the above code if(0== wcscmp(bstrItemNode, L"Machine")) { if(MachineCount++!=-1) { SS.push_back(MachineList); } //printf("value of count is %d\n",count); count++; //printf("value of count is %d\n",count); isMachineList=TRUE; MachineList=new MACHINELIST; MachineCount++; }i am getting the following error error C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PMACHINELIST' to 'MACHINELIST &&' –