# How to pass the stl list in the function as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stl, vector

I have a base class like:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun() const =0;
};

class Derived: public Base 
{
    virtual void fun()
    {
        //implemtation of fun
    }
};
```

I have a global structure:

```
struct Mystruct {
    int a;
    char *b;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

Then i added the structure to a vector:

```
List  = new MYSTRUCT;
vector<MYSTRUCT*> SS;
SS.push_back(List);
```

How can i pass the this vector to the fun function and access the struct in the function?

Comment: There is no "list" here. And since I'm already commenting, there is also no "STL" here, and your function is missing a `()`, and the English word `I` is capitalised when the proper effort is put into it, and I could go on about some other issues with this question but people don't like me going on a rantfest.

Comment: No need to downvote!! It's a legal question, even if the OP has his difficulties understanding C++ usage. (@LightnessRacesinOrbit Note I'm not upvoting the question to 'balance')

Comment: Downvoters should consider editing the question to get some reasonable C++ code in the sample, or at least leave a comment about their reasons ...

Comment: I put about as much effort into leaving a comment regarding my downvote as the OP did in writing the question. More, actually. This is low-quality, low-effort, highly-localised and difficult to parse. That's why I downvoted it. And, @g-makulik, lol :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I absolutely agree. I'm also tempted to downvote ;-) ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're so prolific in posting on the net I can't find a reference to work out where your name comes from is it a quote or something personal?

Comment: As explained in my answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143836/how-to-add-structure-to-the-stl-list), you need to pass a **type** as a template parameter for `std::vector`. `MYSTRUCT` is not a type. It is an instance.

Comment: @Lightness Fair point but consider not picking on “i”. Spelling it with a capital makes as much sense as spelling “internet” with a capital first letter: none. Unlike spelling “internet” in lower case (which has now been adopted by a few prominent magazines), “i” has not yet become common usage but we may get there yet.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "internet" has become an accepted non-proper noun. "I" has not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit “I” isn’t (and never was) a proper noun. It’s a pronoun, and the reasons for its capitalisation [are unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(pronoun)#Capitalization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem confused about the meaning of this:

```
struct Mystruct
{
int a;
char *b;
}MYSTRUCT;
```

This is a declaration of a struct called `Mystruct` *and* an instance of `Mystruct` called `MYSTRUCT`. So when you create `std::vectors` or `std::lists` to hold these structs, you need to use the *type* as template parameter:

```
std::vector<Mystruct> v0; // vector holding 0 Mystructs
```

If you want a vector holding pointers, you need

```
std::vector<Mystruct*> v1;
```

This will simply not compile because `MYSTRUCT` is not a type:

```
std::vector<MYSTRUCT*>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like that:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun(const std::vector<Mystruct*>& list) const =0;
};

class Derived:public Base 
{
public:
    virtual void fun(const std::vector<Mystruct*>& list)
    {
        //implemtation of fun
    }
};
```

But your sample shows that you might have other problems understanding how to design C++ classes (e.g. you don't need to use this C like struct definition syntax with C++).

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right. I didn't try to get s.th. compilable. Just wanted to point the OP into some 'direction' ...